# Core i5-5200 and Turbo Boost

Tags: intel-core-i5, turbo-boost

Do i have to manually install Turbo Boost on my PC, shouldn't it have come pre-installed.
If I have to download and install it, can anyone please suggest a reliable download link?

Comment: Intel Turbo boost is not software, but a feature of i5 processors, which is completely automatic, and out of the users control. It is already running as it is supposed to. Please note that for best results here at superuser, if you have reason to believe Turbo Boost is not working, or think it should help you more with a specific problem, please post about the problem, instead of your theoretical solution. Often you will find that the right answer is completely different that you expect. cheers.

Comment: [5200 supports turbo boost by default](http://ark.intel.com/products/85212/Intel-Core-i5-5200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz), nothing needed to install.

Answer (score 5):

Turbo Boost is not a software (that can be installed), but a hardware feature on the CPU.

The computer motherboard have a certain control in that it can ask the CPU to enable or disable some features such as Turbo. But in general, turbo is enabled by default.

If you want to confirm, you should be able to find whether it is enabled or not by looking at your BIOS settings, which you can access through the option menu that is available for a few seconds when your computer boots.

Answer (score 0):

As long as i read about Intel core processors, Turbo Boost is a feature from the CPU. The feature is usually enabled by default. You have to read your CPU specification to know whether your CPU supports Turbo Boost feature or doesn't.